# http-auth-interceptor is not settings the headers correctly

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I have 2 issues using [http-auth-interceptor](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth). Let talk about the first one.

- When the API return 401 (for the first time), the application is catching the event `event:auth-loginRequired` within a directive present in the index.html and display the modal so the user can login. Then on authentication success, the login script is calling `authService.loginConfirmed(user, httpConfigCallback())`. In the callback I'm setting 2 HTTP headers in order to update the API token. The problem is that I cannot see the header set when the initial request is dequeued. Here is my code:

  ```
  $scope.user = UserAuthService.getUser();

  // User is now auth, we confirm it
  authService.loginConfirmed($scope.user, function(config){
      config.headers["API_USER"] = $scope.user.guid;
      config.headers['API_TOKEN'] = $scope.user.api_token;
      return config;
  });
  ```

But the header is not set:

[image]

- The second issue I have is that the dequeued request is returning a 401, but the directive is not catching it anymore and so it's not displaying the login screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working well. The request header screenshot was the one from the `OPTIONS` request. It was denied by my server because I did not allowed my additional headers. I've added this:

```
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,API_USER,API_TOKEN");
```

Now everything is working well.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Angular interceptors to set your config headers.

Aa example: [UserAuthInterceptor](https://github.com/williamverdolini/discitur-web/blob/master/app/modules/user/UserService.js#L471)